# Как задать winapi-константы в C#-приложении?

Tags: winapi, c#

Часть нашел в сети, например `WM_ACTIVATE = 0x6 ... WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x20C; SW_HIDE = 0 ... SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11;`. Сейчас мне нужны аргументы функции `SetWindowLongPtr, GWL_STYLE` и т.д. Какими константами их задать? Вообще, как я понял, значения должны быть где-то в заголовочных файлах `С++`, но я не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй поискать в папке "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include"
в файле winuser.h, например